# How to remove the prefix from an e-mail in a table?

Tags: text-processing

this is the INPUT:

```
$ echo -e '<tr><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>someone.something@example.com</td></tr>\n<tr><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>foo.bar@example2.com</td></tr>'
<tr><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>someone.something@example.com</td></tr>
<tr><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>foo.bar@example2.com</td></tr>
```

this is the OUTPUT with SOME MAGIC!

```
$ echo -e '<tr><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>someone.something@example.com</td></tr>\n<tr><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>foo.bar@example2.com</td></tr>' | SOMEMAGIC
<tr><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>example.com</td></tr>
<tr><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>example2.com</td></tr>
```

**My question:** how can "SOMEMAGIC" remove the prefixes before "@" and the "@" itself?

The unique delimiter is the

```
"</td><td>"
```

XXX and YYY could be anything, so it could be ex.: "someone.something@example.com" too :\

p.s.: So the question is, how can someone remove the prefix from:

someone.something@example.com

so it will be:

example.com

in this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ echo -e '<tr><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>someone.something@example.com</td></tr>\n<tr><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>foo.bar@example2.com</td></tr>' | \
awk -F'</td><td>' 'gsub(/.*@/,"",$9)' OFS='</td><td>'
<tr><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>example.com</td></tr>
<tr><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>YYY</td><td>example2.com</td></tr>
```

`</td><td>` delimiter split the line into `9` fields. The email is field number `9th`, you can remove all characters before `@` in `9th` field to get desired output.

If you don't have to use `awk`, you can try `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's#(.*)<td>.*@(.*)#$1<td>$2#'
```

Comment: Simply. wow.. Bless you.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
echo '....' | sed 's,>[^<@]*@,>,g'
```